# TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.timedelta' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, datetime

Folks, I am new to Python and I see this error (below) when running this piece of code, what am I doing wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date = (datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
new_date = date + timedelta(days=10)
print(new_date)
```

ERROR:

```
    new_date = date + timedelta(days=10)
TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.timedelta' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: `date` is a *string* by using `strftime()`. What did you expect to happen from adding a string to a timedelta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You converted a `datetime` object to a string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
'02/22/17'
```

You can't sum a string and a `timedelta` object. You probably wanted to get a `datetime.date()` object instead:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
print(today + timedelta(days=10))
```

or extract the date with the [`datetime.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date):

```
today = datetime.today().date()
print(today + timedelta(days=10))
```

If you still need a string object, convert **after** applying date arithmetic:

```
future = today + timedelta(days=10)
print(future.strftime('%m/%d/%y'))
```